# Dynamically assigning div height in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div with class "divItemclass" for this class, I have put height as auto. This div contains some data (text/images ). Now I want to change the class to another class when user clicks on the delete button. I am using the below code to do so

```
$("#divRoundItem").removeClass().addClass("divGlowToDelete").fadeIn(500);
```

and in my css

```
.divGlowToDelete
{
background-color:Red;
border:1px solid red;
height:auto;
 }
```

But when this happens, since I had given the height as auto, it is not showing red bg color for the entire div. If I change the height from auto to a fixed height (ex: 20 px), it is showing red color bg as of that much height.

But I can't mention a height as the length of contents comes inside the div is dynamic. How to solve this? I think it would be good if I can take the current height of div and assign it to the new class (divGlowToDelete) at runtime (when changing the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work if you set the height with jQuery after adding the new class?

```
$("#roundItem")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("divGlowToDelete")
    .css("height","auto")
    .fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get or set the height of the div by calling the [`height`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height) method.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an idea to try setting the height of the <div> explicitly with jQuery when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    var $theDiv = $('#divRoundItem');
    $theDiv.css('height', $theDiv.height() + 'px');
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem related to clearing floats?

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html